# AWK split for multiple delimiters lines

Tags: shell, unix, awk, split

I'm trying to split a file using AWK one-line but the code below that I came with is not working properly.

```
awk '
BEGIN { idx=0; file="original_file.split." }
/^REC_DELIMITER.(HIGH|TOP)$/ { idx++ }
/^REC_DELIMITER.TOP$/,/^REC_DELIMITER.(HIGH|TOP)$/ { print > file sprintf("%03d", idx) }
' original_file
```

Test file is "original_file":

```
REC_DELIMITER.TOP
lineA1
lineA2
lineA3
REC_DELIMITER.HIGH
lineB1
lineB2
lineB3
REC_DELIMITER.TOP
lineC1
lineC2
lineC3
REC_DELIMITER.HIGH
lineD1
lineD2
lineD3
```

AWK code above is for REC_DELIMITER.TOP and it is giving me these files:

```
original_file.split.001:
REC_DELIMITER.TOP

original_file.split.003:
REC_DELIMITER.TOP
```

however, I'm trying to get this:

```
original_file.split.001:
REC_DELIMITER.TOP
lineA1
lineA2
lineA3

original_file.split.003:
REC_DELIMITER.TOP
lineC1
lineC2
lineC3
```

There will be other record delimiters, and when needed, we can run for them like REC_DELIMITER.HIGH, this way getting files like below:

```
original_file.split.002:
REC_DELIMITER.HIGH
lineB1
lineB2
lineB3

original_file.split.004:
REC_DELIMITER.HIGH
lineD1
lineD2
lineD3
```

Any help guys is very appreciate, I have been trying to get this working past few days and AWK code above is the best I was able to get. I need now help from AWK masters. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Cramming 4 lines of code onto one line is not helpful to readability. Also get rid of the HTML from your sample input/output unless that really is present in your files.

Comment: thanks.. HTML removed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not very used to AWK, however, plasticide's answer put me towards right direction and I finally got AWK script working as requirements.

In below code, first IF turn echo to 0 if a demilier is found. Second IF turn echo to 1 if the wanted delimiter is found, then the want ones are are split from file.

I know regex could be something like `/^(REC_(DELIMITER\.(TOP|HIGH|LOW)|NO_CATEGORY)$/` but since regex is created dynamically via shellscript that reads from an specific file a list of delimiters, it will look more like in AWK below.

```
awk 'BEGIN {
  idx=0; echo=1; file="original_file.split."
}
{
  #All the delimiters to consider in given file
  if($0 ~ /^(REC_DELIMITER.TOP|REC_DELIMITER.HIGH|REC_DELIMITER.LOW|REC_NO_CATEGORY)$/) {
    echo=0
  }
  #Delimiters that should actually be pulled
  if($0 ~ /^(REC_DELIMITER.HIGH|REC_DELIMITER.LOW)$/ {
    idx++; echo=1
  }
  #Print to a file is match wanted delimmiter
  if(echo) {
    print > file idx
  }
}' original_file
```

Thank you all. I really appreciate it very much.

Comment: Think it's a bit mean not accepting the answer you based your solution on.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
awk '
/REC_DELIMITER\.TOP/ {
    a=1
    b=0
    file = sprintf (FILENAME".split.%03d",++n)
}    
/REC_DELIMITER\.HIGH/ {
    b=1
    a=0
    file = sprintf (FILENAME".split.%03d",++n)
}  
a {
    print $0 > file
}    
b {
    print $0 > file
}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this (untested):

```
awk -v dtype="TOP" '
BEGIN { dbase = "^REC_DELIMITER\\."; delim = dbase dtype "$" }
$0 ~ dbase { inBlock=0 }
$0 ~ delim { inBlock=1; idx++ }
inBlock { print > sprintf("original_file.split.%03d", idx) }
' original_file
```

Comment: really cool this proposed solution, but unfortunately I cannot use 

dbase = "^REC_DELIMITER\\.

delimiters are supposed to change... only file structure won't change.

So there will be files with different delimiters.

Comment: Then just set "delim" explicitly using -v instead of building it from parts BUT if the delimiters can be anything, how do you know when a line contains a delimiter or not? I mean if you're searching for "REC_DELIMITER.TOP" and you find the text "REC_DELIMITER.HIGH" how do you distinguish that from any other line that doesn't contain "REC_DELIMITER.TOP"?

Comment: Delimiters are read from another file.. according to what is being processed. that is why it can be anything. I finally got it working as expected. Thank you for all the help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -vRS=REC_DELIMITER '/^.TOP\n/{print RS $0 > sprintf("original_file.split.%03d",n)};!++n' original_file
```

(Give or take an extra newline at the end.)

Generally, when input is supposed to be treated as a series of multi-line records with a special line as delimiter, the most direct approach is to set RS (and often ORS) to that delimiter.

Normally you'd want to add newlines to its beginning and/or end, but this case is a little special so it's easier without them.

Edited to add: You need GNU Awk for this. Standard Awk considers only the first character of RS.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes so the different delimiters go to the their own file, even when they occur later in the file.  make a file like splitter.awk with the contents below, the chmod +x it and run it with `./splitter.awk original_file`

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  idx=0;
  file="original_file.split.";
  out=""
}
{
  if($0 ~ /^REC_DELIMITER.(TOP|HIGH)/){
    if (!cnt[$0]) {
      cnt[$0] = ++idx;
    }
    out=cnt[$0];
  }
  print >  file sprintf("%03d", out)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer put me towards right direction and I finally got AWK script working as requirements.